# Windows Server 2016 IIS hosted website failed to load dll on a remote file share with remote server's user/password

Tags: iis, dll, access-denied, windows-server-2016

An extended topic of this question: [Windows Server 2016 IIS hosted website failed to load dll on a remote file share on AlibabaCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177459/windows-server-2016-iis-hosted-website-failed-to-load-dll-on-a-remote-file-share)

I have tried to put the IIS website on a remote file share on Windows Server 2012/2016 machine B, and load this IIS website on a Windows Server 2016 machine A. A can access B's file share. However, if A's IIS loads B's file share's website with B's administrator name and password, A's IIS fails to load dlls of the website.

It shows access denied when loading dlls. Loading an html page is fine.
[Access is denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNCik.png)

I have also tried to make the machines domain joined. If I use domain joined account under AD server, loading dlls from remote file share works.

Does anyone know what happened? Why does Windows Server 2016 IIS block remote dll access on a remote file share? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Avoid posting duplicate questions, but edit and improve your original one.

Comment: They are different but similar issues. This one is access denied, last one is Dll load failure: 0x8007003a